# How do I split many variable-sized units of work into equal sized buckets?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, load-balancing

Let's say I have 300-400 units of work, all with different sizes, where the size difference is quite large in some cases. Is it possible to split those up into a fixed number of buckets so I can balance the load across a fixed number of worker threads?

Comment: Sounds like a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: Do you need optimal or good enough solution? Because optiomal would be (I guess) ON(n!)

Comment: @bartop A heuristic would be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you describe is known as Multiprocessor Scheduling problem (which is similar to bin packing problem which is a generalisation of the knapsack problem). Finding the optimal scheduling is known to be NP-hard. Therefore there is no known polynomial time algorithm for finding an optimal scheduling.

A simple heuristic (non-optimal) algorithm is Longest Processing Time:

- Sort the units of work, largest first
- For each unit, place into bucket with earliest end time

Comment: Even better - don't try to predict execution times by putting units of work into separate queues for each worker - if you're wrong in your predictions (and there will be times where you are...) you'll wind up with workers idle while others have work still waiting in their queues.  Rather, have the workers **pull** work from a shared queue (or multiple queues in priority order...) when they're available.  That way you don't have to predict execution times, and all workers will be busy until there's no more units of work at all.

Comment: What @AndrewHenle says.  A lot of multithreading issues are best solved in a similar manner - instead of trying to solve the problem, change the design so that the problem disappears:)